# Redefine precendence of operators in ruby

Tags: ruby

Using ruby, I can overload the operators in my functions. I wonder if I can overload the precedence somehow (cheats are allowed). For example:

```
class Odd
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def +(odd)
    Odd.new(@value - odd.value)
  end

  def *(odd)
    Odd.new(@value / odd.value)
  end
end

a = Odd.new(5)
b = Odd.new(5)
c = Odd.new(5)

puts (a + b * c).value
```

This script prints `4` thanks to the precedence. How can I make it print `0` by evaluating first the sum then the multiplication?

Comment: Make `*` do addition and `+` do multiplication. Or patch and recompile Ruby.

Comment: You could change how Ripper parses your source, but why would you want to?

Comment: I'm curious about what the point of this exercise is. Is your heart full of hate for maintenance programmers or something?

Comment: @muistooshort I'm just a guy trying to learn a programming language.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do this without hacking Ruby itself; of course, doing this would probably break a non-trivial amount of all the other Ruby code you're using. You see, Ruby doesn't know what `a`, `b`, or `c` are when it is figuring out what

```
a + b * c
```

means, it only knows the built-in precedence of the `+` and `*` operators and how to translate those operators to method calls.

You could manually convert the operators to method calls and manually order them according to your preferred precedence:

```
a.+(b).*(c).value
```

but that's pretty nasty (less nasty than confusing everyone by changing the precedence of operators though).

An alternative would be to put `"a + b * c"` into a string and then write your own parser for that string. This would just be a fancy way of dynamically building `a.+(b).*(c)` though.

Then there's the obvious: use parentheses and leave the precedence alone:

```
((a + b) * c).value
```

Comment: +1 for `You see, Ruby doesn't know what a, b, or c are when it is figuring out what (...) means`. That shows exactly why can't be done.

Comment: @fotanus: And doubly so with Ruby since almost anything can change at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the full stack until it is evaluated at last.

```
class Odd
  attr_reader :stack
  def initialize *stack; @stack = stack end
  def + other; Odd.new(*(stack + [:-] + other.stack)) end
  def * other; Odd.new(*(stack + [:/] + other.stack)) end
  def value
    while i = stack.index(:-) do stack[i - 1, 3] = stack[i - 1] - stack[i + 1] end
    while i = stack.index(:/) do stack[i - 1, 3] = stack[i - 1] / stack[i + 1] end
    stack.first
  end
end

a = Odd.new(5)
b = Odd.new(5)
c = Odd.new(5)

puts (a + b * c).value
# => 0
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I wonder about possible strange side effects though.

Comment: It may have side effects, but at least it is locked inside this class. I think the behaviour is pretty much customizable.

Comment: That is actually impressive.